# Scala reflection. Is there a convenient way to verify that reflection class is module class (companion object)?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to find out if the class is an implementation of a companion object, or it's a regular class that corresponds to some type of data.

```
def checkIsCompanionClass(universe:scala.reflect.api.Universe, class:Class[_]):Boolean = {
    val classSymbol = universe.rootMirror.staticClass(cls.getName)
    classSymbol.isModule //or classSymbol.isModuleClass
}
```

I tried this, but isModule and isModuleClass return false for "companion" classs (class name ends with $)

Comment: What's the goal? Reflection is rarely the only/right solution

Comment: I create a utilitarian method in which I need to eliminate $ at the end of the name of the class (object companion). Scala type checker gives such names in AST (blackbox.Context.typeCheck).